# How to copy data into certain parts of a byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, bit, memcpy

I want to create a byte array out of an unknown struct and add a number additionally in the front of this byte array. How do I do this?

I currently have this code:

```
template <class T>
void CopterConnection::infoToByteArray(char *&bit_data, size_t *msglen,
                                       T data) {
    // Determine which kind of element is in the array, will change in the final code
    char typeID = -1;

    *msglen = sizeof(data);
    *msglen += 1;  // take in account of typeID

    // Create the pointer to the byte representation of the struct
    bit_data = new char[*msglen];

    // copy the information from the struct into the byte array
    memcpy(bit_data, &data+1, *msglen-1);
    bit_data[1] = typeID;
}
```

But this is not working. I guess I use the memcpy wrong. I want to copy the unkown struct T into the positions `bit_data[1]` to `bit_data[*end*]`. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: *is not working* means nothing. Please say exactly what happens...

Comment: Is it "working" now you fixed your code?

Comment: If you updated your code in the question to include fixes from answers, then don't do that! It makes the answers useless and the question even more so.

Comment: It is working now, it were some simple errors, but thank you for helping me find them. I updated the question because I thought they would not be the reason of the problem, but only levity.

Comment: This is now not really a very useful question for anyone who wants to solve their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible problem and one definitive problem:

1. The possible problem is that array indexing starts at zero. So you should copy to `bit_data + 1` to skip over the first byte, and then of course use `bit_data[0]` to set the type id.
2. The definitive problem is that `&data + 1` is equal to `(&data)[1]`, and that will be out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*. You should just copy from `&data`.

Putting it all together the last to lines should be

```
memcpy(bit_data + 1, &data, *msglen-1);
bit_data[0] = typeID;
```

---

There is another possible problem, which depends on what you're doing with the data in `bit_data` and what `T` is. If `T` is not a [POD type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) then you simply can not expect a bitwise copy (what `memcpy` does) to work very well.

Also if `T` is a class or structure with members that are pointers then you can't save those to disk or transfer to another computer or even to another process on the same computer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few bugs in there, in addition to the fact you are messing around with new.

The `memcpy` line itself you use `&data + 1` as the source which here will be undefined behaviour. It will add sizeof(data) bytes to the address which is copied so in the stack somewhere and whilst "one past the end" is a valid pointer so this address is valid in pointer arithmetic, nothing you read from it will be, nor anything after it.

`bit_data[1]` is the 2nd character in your buffer.

Comment: I'm sorry for that